# Image localization not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, localization

I have an image array on my code & its shown on a scrollview.
Everything work great & i see the images.
I did localization to every photo i have, the localization process made me a new folder with the relevant language and copied every image that is in the english folder to the new language, then i took the images of the second language & copied them to the new language folder (replaced the old ones).
It should work great but it doesn't change the language.
I tried to close xcode & delete the app from the simulator but it didn't help.
What alse could it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if images are correctly added to project AND to target?

Comment: Yes, all the images are in my bundle & in the correct folder. every image has 2 versions, each for every language. when i click on each of the two images in the bundle, i see the two versions. it seems to be ok but it doesn't transform to the other language :\

Comment: In XCode you can check _target membership_ of certain file this way: open File Inspector (View->Utilities->Show File Inspector). Then select the file you're interested in in Project Navigator. On the right sight of the screen you should see "Target Membership" panel. Check if there's a checkmark next to the target.

Comment: rokjarc thanks for your help. there's a checkmark next to every target, but I managed to solve it by doing the "clean" option again, close xcode, delete the app from the simulator & close it & reopen everything again & it worked!.. conclusion: simualtor sucks.. :)

Comment: Hey good to hear! :) As for conclusion: yes, cleaning & restarting & etc gets under your skin after a while :)